# Inconsistent ResultSet from Procedure with Variables

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, where, empty-string

I'm working on building a procedure with two inputs, and the Syntax checks out, but the result-set is not consistent with the logic.

In this question, there are in actual fact two questions. Number 1 is the most important in this context. Number 2 is less important.

---

### **1. Inconsistency**

***Data Sets***

```
    [tbl] employees (PRIM)           [tbl] loc_offices (SEC)        [tbl] emp_types (SEC)
+-----------------+-----------+  +-----------------+-----------+  +-----------+-----------+
|     COLUMNS     | DATATYPE  |  |     COLUMNS     | DATATYPE  |  |  COLUMNS  | DATATYPE  |
+-----------------+-----------+  +-----------------+-----------+  +-----------+-----------+
| emp_id          | <VARCHAR> |  | office_id       |   <INT>   |  | emp_type  | <VARCHAR> |
| emp_lastname    | <VARCHAR> |  | office_name     | <VARCHAR> |  | type_desc | <VARCHAR> |
| emp_firstname   | <VARCHAR> |  | office_town     | <VARCHAR> |  +-----------+-----------+
| emp_replocation | <VARCHAR> |  | office_province |   <INT>   |
| emp_type        | <VARCHAR> |  +-----------------+-----------+
| emp_status      |  <INT>    |
| emp_image       |  <BLOB>   |
+-----------------+-----------+
```

***Procedure***

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `getEmployees`(
    IN location INT(1),
    IN stafftype VARCHAR(1)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        emp_id,
        emp_lastname,
        emp_firstname,
        office_name,
        type_desc,
        emp_status
    FROM
        employees t1
    INNER JOIN loc_offices t2
        ON t1.emp_replocation = t2.office_id
    INNER JOIN emp_types t3 
        ON t1.emp_type = t3.emp_type
    WHERE
        IF ( 
            location = '%' AND stafftype = '%', 
            (
                t1.emp_replocation = location
                AND t1.emp_type = stafftype
            ),
            IF ( 
                location = '%' AND stafftype != '%', 
                t1.emp_type = stafftype,
                IF (
                    location != '%' AND stafftype = '%',
                    t1.emp_replocation = stafftype,
                    '%'
                )
            )
        )
    ORDER BY 
        emp_id ASC
    ;
END
```

***Test Calls***

1. `CALL getEmployees();`

   *• Expected Outcome:* 
   Return all records in data set

   *• Outcome:* 
   "Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE db.getEmployees; expected 2, got 0"
2. `CALL getEmployees(NULL, NULL);`

   *• Expected Outcome:* 
   Return all records in data set

   *• Outcome:* 
   Empty Result-set
3. `CALL getEmployees(1, NULL);`

   *• Expected Outcome:* 
   Return records in data set filtered by **emp_replocation** only

   *• Outcome:* 
   Empty Result-set
4. `CALL getEmployees(NULL, "C");`

   *• Expected Outcome:* 
   Return records in data set filtered by **emp_type** only

   *• Outcome:* 
   All records, with correct **emp_type**
5. `CALL getEmployees(1, "C");`

   *• Expected Outcome:* 
   Return records in data set filtered by **emp_type** and **emp_replocation**

   *• Outcome:* 
   Empty Result-set

***Changes Attempted***

- Replacing `(!)= '%'` with `IS (NOT) NULL`
- Replacing `'%'` with `FALSE`

***The Question***

Based on this information, why is the location parameter ignored, and what is the correction recommended in this situation?

---

### **2. The second question**

I've researched this, but unsure of the correct approach. ***How can I handle empty Procedure Calls?***

In the case of `getEmployees()`, it currently results in an incomplete call error, which is expected, instead of selecting all records without filters.

Comment: *Data Sets* Add CREATE TABLE + INSET INTO scripts. Or create a fiddle. *Test Calls `CALL getEmployees();`* - no optional parameters in MySQL. 2nd Q. is unsolvable.

Comment: How are the `%` replaced?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `getEmployees`( IN location INT(1),
                                 IN stafftype VARCHAR(1) )
SELECT ... /* output columns list */
... /* source tables with JOIN conditions */
WHERE COALESCE(parameter, table.field) = table.field /* replace with real names */
... /* another conditions, grouping, ordering */
;
```

If `parameter` (`location` or `stafftype`) is not NULL then the condition is equal to `WHERE parameter = table.field`.

If `parameter` value is NULL then the condition is equal to `WHERE table.field = table.field` which is TRUE until `table.field` is NULL (if such records must be returned too then use `<=>` operator instead of `=`).

Comment: Could you please explain this approach?

Comment: @JohanBrink Some explainations added.

Comment: thank you, appreciated.